# How can I make new rows in Gnumeric keep the previous formatting?

Tags: gnumeric

I want to build for me a sheet with text columns for `First Name`, `Name`, `Country`, `Politic group`, `email`, `position in the institution` (e.g.: deputy or president of one group etc.), `web page with more information` (often a page of the politic group supporting the person), perhaps `more` (e.g. "binational" or "ride on horses" or "have dogs" or "drives in formula 1 competitions"). All that should be in text form and I will only use the excellent faculty of Gnumeric to sort and actualize the text.

But my experience is, if I insert new rows, the preformatted columns forget their format in the new row(s).

Perhaps I have to start from a template giving the columns a definitive format? But I did never learn how to create my own new template in Gnumeric!

How can I make new rows in Gnumeric keep the previous formatting?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean format? Can you provide a screenshot of what you need and what you get? [Edit] your question to add that information. Thanks!

Comment: Mark the formated cells, grab a corner and pull to cover the new cells. It should work to copy the format to the new cells in most spreadsheet tools.